# Deconstruct tuple and store each element into a List of their respective element type

Tags: c#

I encountered a use case where it was needed to store each element of a tuple into a list of their respective type of the tuple element. To streamline this feature I wrote a method extension that I overloaded for different sized tuples. The code is quite basic and does not do a lot but I thought you could give me some feedback on how to improve it and/or how to do it in a more elegant way

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public static class UserSpecificTupleExtension
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1 </param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1>(this Tuple<T1> value, ref List<T1> List1)
    {
        var a = value.Item1;
        List1.Add(a);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1</param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1>(this ValueTuple<T1> value, ref List<T1> List1)
    {
        var a = value.Item1;
        List1.Add(a);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1</param>
    /// <param name="List2">instance of a List which holds type T2</param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this Tuple<T1, T2> value, ref List<T1> List1, ref List<T2> List2)
    {
        var (a, b) = value;
        List1.Add(a);
        List2.Add(b);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1</param>
    /// <param name="List2">instance of a List which holds type T2</param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this ValueTuple<T1, T2> value, ref List<T1> List1, ref List<T2> List2)
    {
        var (a, b) = value;
        List1.Add(a);
        List2.Add(b);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1</param>
    /// <param name="List2">instance of a List which holds type T2</param>
    /// <param name="List3">instance of a List which holds type T3</param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2, T3>(this Tuple<T1, T2, T3> value, ref List<T1> List1, ref List<T2> List2, ref List<T3> List3)
    {
        var (a, b, c) = value;
        List1.Add(a);
        List2.Add(b);
        List3.Add(c);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T2">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="T3">type of tuple element</typeparam>
    /// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
    /// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1</param>
    /// <param name="List2">instance of a List which holds type T2</param>
    /// <param name="List3">instance of a List which holds type T3</param>
    public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2, T3>(this ValueTuple<T1, T2, T3> value, ref List<T1> List1, ref List<T2> List2, ref List<T3> List3)
    {
        var (a, b, c) = value;
        List1.Add(a);
        List2.Add(b);
        List3.Add(c);
    }
}
```

And here a small sample program:

````
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {

        var listA = new List<int>();
        var listB = new List<string>();

        var listC = new List<char>();

        (1, "4", '_').Deconstruct(ref listA, ref listB, ref listC);
        listA.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        listB.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

```
````

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Feel free to post a follow-up question if the code has changed significantly enough.

Comment: @Mast i will keep that in mind for the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## `ref` parameters

Make sure you fully understand what `ref` does and when it's appropriate to use it.

`ref` gives you an *alias to the variable passed into the method*, so only use `ref` when you need to modify *the original variable passed by the caller*.

`List<T>` is already a reference type: anything passed to a `List<T>` parameter will already be a reference to an object of that type. You can happily modify the object via that reference without needing `ref`.

## Parameter types

It's a good rule of thumb to accept the least specific type possible as a parameter.

Because you are only calling `Add` on the given lists, you don't actually require a concrete `List<T>` type to be passed. All lists that you'll ever be interested in implement `IList<T>` which has an `Add` method, so you should accept `IList<T>` instead.

You could go even further: `IList<T>.Add` is inherited from `ICollection<T>` so if you don't care about order then go ahead and loosen those parameter types to `ICollection<T>`.

## Method header

Good on you for documenting your public methods! It's a great practice to get into; keep on doing it.

I do a have a few suggestions:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deconstructs a tuple and stores each indivdual value into a provided non-null List
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T1">type of tuple element</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">Instance which calls this method</param>
/// <param name="List1">instance of a List which holds type T1 </param>
```

You (rightly) specify in the summary that the list must be non-null, but you don't actually check for `null` anywhere: your code will crash if `null` is passed.

Common convention in C# is to perform argument validation at the start of the method and throw an appropriate `ArgumentException` (or one of its child types):

```
public static void Deconstruct<T1>(this Tuple<T1> value, List<T1> List1)
{
    if (List1 is null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(List1));
    // ...
}
```

You could claim, "What's the difference? It'll just crash anyway with an ArgumentNullException instead!"

The difference is:

1. The exception is more clear to the user that *they* got the argument wrong, and
2. By performing validation at the start you fail *fast*, rather than at some point in the middle. Imagine what happens in your `Deconstruct<T1, T2>` if the first list is non-null but the second one is null -- you'll have modified only one of the given lists! Who gets to clean up the state of your now half-modified input arguments?

While we're at it, change that parameter name from `List1` to `list`. C# convention dictates `camelCase` for parameter names, and the `1` is redundant for this overload.

## Deconstruction

```
public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this ValueTuple<T1, T2> value, ref List<T1> List1, ref List<T2> List2)
{
    var (a, b) = value;
    List1.Add(a);
    List2.Add(b);
}
```

You gain nothing by doing `var (a, b) = value;`. It just adds an unnecessary deconstruction of `value`. You can already access the individual elements using the `ItemN` fields:

```
public static void Deconstruct<T1, T2>(this ValueTuple<T1, T2> value, IList<T1> list1, IList<T2> list2)
{
    list1.Add(value.Item1);
    list2.Add(value.Item2);
}
```

I might also suggest using a slightly different name from `Deconstruct`, since the compiler [sometimes gives special meaning to methods called `Deconstruct`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/deconstruct#deconstructing-user-defined-types). It wouldn't *actually* do anything special in this case because it doesn't meet all the requirements, but it might still mislead or confuse someone who's familiar with that feature. Maybe name them `DeconstructToLists` or something -- it avoids that ambiguity while making it more clear what it does and what its side effect is.

---

Aside from that, I don't mind the repeatedness of the code. C# does not have first-class support for iterating over generic type arguments so any attempt to generalize your code will certainly result in a mess of reflection and boxing. There is such a small, finite set of generic flavours of `Tuple` and `ValueTuple` that I wouldn't invest the time in generalizing it further.

Comment: Thanks for this great answer. The reason for using ref ... well, I just had in mind I must change obj and the change must be visible outside of the method. I think rust starts to creep into my thought patterns XD

I totally forgot about ICollection in c#. currently, I just use IEnumerable for almost everything. regarding the naming that is certainly a good point didn't know about the special meaning of that method name thanks for that information.

Regarding the null check... forgot to write them down but it was intended^^ as you have seen in my comments. Again thanks for taking a look :D

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Jeff's comments, you could also change your approach a bit. The reason you use `List<T1>` is you want to do this with multiple `Tuple<T1>` don't you? You might have lists of tuples in your code here and there e.g. `List<Tuple<T1, T2>>`. Instead of creating methods which need to accept other objects as parameters and change their state - construct and return right in your extension method.

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a list of tuples and returns a tuple of lists.
/// </summary>
public static Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>> ToListTuple<T1, T2>( this IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>> tupleList )
{
    return new Tuple<List<T1>, List<T2>>(
        tupleList.Select( inputObj => inputObj.Item1 ).ToList(),
        tupleList.Select( inputObj => inputObj.Item2 ).ToList()
    );
}
```

It might seem an overkill at first. Writing methods as pure functions is however something I would highly recommend. Pure functions are functions which do not modify state of any object, they just return things and their results are *repeatable*. Also if you take this approach the operation can be easily reversed:

```
/// <summary>
/// Takes a tuple of lists and returns a list of tuples.
/// </summary>
public static List<Tuple<T1, T2>> ToTupleList<T1, T2>(this Tuple<IEnumerable<T1>, IEnumerable<T2>> listTuple)
{
    return listTuple.Item1.Zip(listTuple.Item2, MakeNewTuple).ToList();
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns a tuple containing two objects.
/// </summary>
private static Tuple<T1, T2> MakeNewTuple<T1, T2>(T1 t1Item, T2 t2Item)
{
    return new Tuple<T1, T2>(t1Item, t2Item);
}
```

To support other sizes of `Tuple<...>` objects you will need to write additional overloads.

Comment: Very interesting. If the given use case would contain tuples containing list this is certainly a way to go. Unfortunately in my case I need to take reference from pre-existing lists and insert the the elements accordingly because we cannot change the given api. Nonetheless I really like your approach. Thanks a lot.